# Man doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, manpage

I recently updated my machine from Ubuntu 16 to 18
Now man doesn't work at all

```
man man
man: nroff: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: command exited with status 159: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=98n -rLT=98n -Tutf8)
```

I read few forums about it but I didn't find solution

Man version is

```
2.8.3
```

uname output is

```
Linux user 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a`

Comment: @steeldriver done

Comment: Thanks - out of interest, does `MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 man man` behave any differently?

Comment: @steeldriver, yes , with this prefix man shows me correct output

Comment: @steeldriver, I added this property  to my bashrc , is it expected behavior or some bug in man ?

Comment: It's some kind of bug I think - tbh I don't know what `MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1` does exactly, but it should be regarded as a temporary workaround rather than a real fix

Comment: Ok , do you want to post the answer so I could mark this question as completed ?

Comment: @steeldriver, I will post the answer with the reference to our discussion

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved with the help from @steeldriver
Solution:
If you can run man command with the following prefix:

```
MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 man man
```

Then you should add this flag to your **.bashrc** file

```
export MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1
```

The same problem was mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339132/reinstall-man-pages-fix-man/426204
However the question was created two years ago and still it doesn't work properly